# How to install ionicLab on red hat Linux?

Tags: ionic-framework, redhat

I am having red hat Linux .After extracting the downloaded IonicLab-linux-x64.tar.gz I double clicked the ionic-lab but its not opening . It says to find an application to open it. Can anybody help here?

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command to extract it from the archive first:

```
tar zxvf IonicLab-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

You would be left with most likely a directory called "ionic-lab". Now go into that directory:

```
cd ionic-lab
```

You would then be able to run the file under this directory

Comment: When I double click on the file inside ionic-lab directory ,nothing happens.